# Start two http servers in Django

Tags: django, multithreading, python-2.7

I have working application on port 8080(Django 1.6). It binds to external network interface. I would like to add one more http listener inside my Django app. E.G. one more http server on port 8000, and bind it to internal network interface only.

Is it possible in Django?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "internal network interface only"? Are you running some sort of container? How do you intend to use the internal port? There is nothing stopping you from running multiple servers from the same Django application code.

Comment: @GjertG, I have ip bind to internet. And ip for local network.

Comment: @GjertG, could you please provide some example?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want Django to do in this case. Networking should not be done by the Django application, but rather be handled by a proxy server such as Nginx or limited by a firewall.

Comment: @GjertG, yes Nginx will bind ports to network addresses, I am only interested in possibility to serve in two ports in Django and best practices about that: eg should I create thread or its created by Django, etc...

Comment: If you want to run two separate instances of the same Django application but at different ports my best guess would be that you use two separate instances of Gunicorn/Daphne (or whatever WSGI you use) and then use Nginx to listen to two ports, redirecting to the correct application. If you use separate WSGI's there wont be a problem.

Comment: @GjertG, but correct me if I'am wrong, will it be two separate processes?

Comment: Yep that would be true. Better to have a NGINX/ or a reverse proxy server, listen to two ports and redirect them both to django

Comment: If you configure them as two separate named applications in Gunicorn then yes. They would have separate memory instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understod your use cases correctly here, my recommendation would be to run two separate Gunicorn/Daphne (or whatever WSGI/ASGI you use) instances and use NGINX as a proxy to serve the Django application over different ports.

This will create separate memory spaces for each application and also make them separate processes.

If you intend to increase the performance of your application, then Gunicorn workers would be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And one more question: If I would like them to share memory? How could I start two http servers in one django process?

Comment: Then I would use one WSGI service and simply make NGINX proxy direct both ports to the same application. This is more of a networking/nginx problem than a Django problem to be honest. I would lookup NGINX and WSGI service you are using.